Plotting potentials of 2d parallel plate capacitor in 0V box. Plots coming out wrong?
I'm trying to plot the potential, equipotential, and electric field lines of a parallel plate capacitor in a box of 0V 2 dimensionally. Only the voltage on the plates and the distance between the plates are given. When I initially made the plot I assumed that the charge density was zero since the plates are equal and opposite. But the plot came out suspicious (potentials are skewed to the left and vectors point towards the positive V plate. Aren't the vectors suppose to point towards the negative?). Problem Linked here
I'm using the Gauss-Seidel method with overrelaxation to calculate the potentials.
L=100
a=1
e0=8.85e-12
p=0
w=0.9
iterations=0
tolerance=1e-6
dvmax=100
dec=4
vpot=np.zeros((L,L))
vpot[20:80,20:21]=1
vpot[20:80,80:81]=-1
xy = np.linspace(0,L-1,L)
xydec=xy[::dec]
while dvmax>tolerance:
      iterations+=1
      dvmax=0
      for i in range(1,L-1):
          for j in range(1,L-1):
              vnew=(vpot[i-1,j]+vpot[i+1,j]+vpot[i,j-1]+vpot[i,j+1]+(p*(a**2)/e0))/4
              dv=(1+w)*(vnew-vpot[i,j])
              if abs(dv)>dvmax:
                 dvmax=abs(dv)
              vpot[i,j]+=dv
print(f'Number of iterations: {iterations}')
plt.imshow(vpot, origin='lower')
plt.plasma()
plt.colorbar()
plt.title(f'Plot of Positive Potentials and Centered Charge Density with Tolerance {tolerance}')
plt.figure()
cv=plt.contour(vpot,15,colors='k', linestyles='solid')
plt.clabel(cv, fontsize=8, inline=True)
plt.title('Contour of Potentials')
plt.figure()
Ex=np.zeros((L,L))
Ey=np.zeros((L,L))
for j in range(1,L-1):
          for k in range(1,L-1):
              if k==0:
                 Ex[j,k] = -(vpot[j,k+1] - vpot[j,k])/a
              elif k==L-1:
                 Ex[j,k] = -(vpot[j,k] - vpot[j,k-1])/a
              else:
                 Ex[j,k] = -(vpot[j,k+1] - vpot[j,k-1])/(2*a)
              if j==0:
                 Ey[j,k] = -(vpot[j+1,k] - vpot[j,k])/a
              elif j==L-1:
                 Ey[j,k] = -(vpot[j,k] - vpot[j-1,k])/a
              else:
                 Ey[j,k] = -(vpot[j+1,k] - vpot[j-1,k])/(2*a)
Exdec = Ex[::dec,::dec]
Eydec = Ey[::dec,::dec]
plt.quiver(xydec,xydec,Exdec,Eydec)
plt.title('Electric Field Vectors')
plt.show()

I'm honestly stuck on what is wrong other than my assumption that the charge density rho, or p in my code, is zero. But I don't know how to calculate the charge considering I'm only given the voltage on each plate and their separation distance.
Plot of potentials and equipotential
Plot of field vectors

You are updating ALL internal potentials in the Gauss-Seidel iteration. You are supposed to keep those that you set as 1 and -1 constant. Probably the easiest way of dealing with this is to mark those points for non-update:
vpot=np.zeros((L,L));   vfixed=np.zeros((L,L))
vpot[20:80,20:21]=1;    vfixed[20:80,20:21] = 1
vpot[20:80,80:81]=-1;   vfixed[20:80,80:81] = 1

Then, in your loop you can just skip any points for which vfixed[] is non-zero:
  for i in range(1,L-1):
      for j in range(1,L-1):
          if vfixed[i,j] != 0: continue

Then your output looks reasonable:



I appreciate the help and I understand the idea but I'm a bit confused on the logic of the code. Why are there two different arrays? Why is both conditions in vfixed equal to 1 when one of the plates is  -1? Which array am I looping through and plotting? Could you break down the code lines a bit more?

There is a second more subtle problem in that you are not applying Gauss-Seidel consistently to the previous set of potentials. The previous line already processed is then included in the computation of the next line. To obtain fastest convergence you either need to work between two buffers (or buffer the results and only write them back to your working array when they are outside the zone that you are using to compute G-S. You can protect the bounding box at V=0 by a suitable choice of indexing range but you have to reimpose the two electrodes each time around or avoid updating them.

The array vfixed[] is just an array whose elements are 1 if the potential is fixed there and 0 if not. (It has nothing to do with potentials of 1 or -1.) It’s simply there as an indicator of whether the point is allowed to be updated. You are looping exactly as you did before, except that you skip one iteration of the loop (the continue statement) if the potential there is fixed. Martin Brown, you seem to be describing the Jacobi method, rather than Gauss-Seidel.
